# using Windown key & numeric keypad

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

In **Windows7**, we can use `<Window>` key with `numeric` key to quick select the n th window in taskbar.
For sample : if I want to view 3rd window, I use combo `<Window>` key + `<3>` key
But we can't use numeric key in the numpad for this action.
so, I post this question to ask whether or not we can use `Window` key and numeric key in numpad to quick select windows in the taskbar?

---

I'm trying with some pieces of code with [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), but still don't find anyway to do it.

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't look like you can use the numeric keyboard for this, only the top row.

I can't find a reference to confirm, just through trying various installations.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, from my experience, the key combo you've mentioned can be used as a shortcut to quick select programs from the taskbar.

On my windows box, hitting the `<Window>` + `3` key brings up the third shortcut that's been pinned to my taskbar. If the program is already open, then the program is brought to the foreground, otherwise the program is launched.

Comment: -1 Initial question already stated this?